# Is there a way to give different parameters to a single job in helm charts having parallelism

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This is my job configuration when parallelism: 2

```
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 60
  backoffLimit: 0
  parallelism: 2
```

Two pods for the same job will come up how do I give two different parameters to the two pods using helm charts

I have tried to do this like this
Below is my helm template for the job.

```
{{- range $index := until (.Values.replicaCount | int)  }}
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: alpine-base-{{ index $.Values.ip_range $index }}
  labels:
    app: alpine-app
    chart: alpine-chart
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": "hook-succeeded"
spec:
  ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 60
  backoffLimit: 0
  completionMode: Indexed
  parallelism: {{ $.Values.replicaCount }}
  completions: {{ $.Values.replicaCount }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app_type: base
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: alpine-base
        image: "{{ $.Values.global.imageRegistry }}/{{ $.Values.global.image.repository }}:{{ $.Values.global.image.tag }}"
        imagePullPolicy: "{{ $.Values.global.imagePullPolicy }}"
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /scripts
            name: scripts-vol
        env:
        - name: IP
          value: {{ index $.Values.slave_producer.ip_range $index }}
        - name: SLEEP_TIME
          value: {{ $.Values.slave_producer.sleepTime }}
        command: ["/bin/bash"]
        args: ["/scripts/slave_trigger_script.sh"]
        ports:
        - containerPort: 1093
        - containerPort: 5000
        - containerPort: 3445
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: "1024Mi"
            cpu: "1024m"
          limits:
            memory: "1024Mi"
            cpu: "1024m"
      volumes:
        - name: scripts-vol
          configMap:
            name: scripts-configmap
      restartPolicy: Never
{{- end }}
```

But both pods get the same IP in the environment variable

Comment: What are you trying to make different? If they are different, it isn't *parallel*-ism...

Comment: env:
        - name: IP
          value: {{ index $.Values.slave_producer.ip_range $index }} only this variable needs to change per pod

Comment: ***WHY*** are you trying to change values per *pod*? Pods should generally be disposably reproducible with the given settings. If a pod restarts, how would it know which of these values to apply? I'd rethink your design. What are you trying to accomplish with this? Is it something you could do with single pods in two separate jobs? Separate releases? Could each reach out to a simple controller service endpoint to *ask* for their values once they are running? Without a lot more info, this just doesn't sound like what I'd expect from a good k8s design.